# Is there a fix for VS 2008 after the Silverlight 4 windows update?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I installed a windows update for Silverlight on my Win 7 64-bit PC yesterday, and today when I started VS 2008, I got the following error:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
```

Package Load Failure

Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Silverlight.SLPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Silverlight, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' has failed to load properly ( GUID = {CB22EE0E-4072-4AE7-96E2-90FCCF879544} ). Please contact package vendor for assistance. Application restart is recommended, due to possible environment corruption. Would you like to disable loading this package in the future? You may use 'devenv /resetskippkgs' to re-enable package loading.

```
---------------------------
Yes   No   
---------------------------
```

Is there an update for the VS integration as well?

Here's the information on the Windows Update-based Silverlight update:

```
Update for Microsoft Silverlight (KB982926)

Download size: 8.2 MB

Update type: Important
```

This update to Silverlight improves security and reliability, and adds a variety of performance and functional enhancements including support for web-conferencing, printing support and improved support for video, networking and rich internet applications. This update is backward compatible with web applications built using previous versions of Silverlight.

More information: 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=185925

Help and Support: 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=105787

Comment: You'd better uninstall it if Silverlight dev is important to you.  Report this problem at connect.microsoft.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [blog](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/06/03/silverlight-4-minor-update-june-2010.aspx) about a June update to Silverlight.  Consider downloading and installing the Windows Developer Runtime that Tim provides a link to.

The update may have installed the standard runtime but dev machines need this developer version of the runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That was interesting - the install failed saying the same version was already installed (I didn't try removing the current version first), but VS 2008 now starts up ok. I'll have to reboot and try again, and see if VS 2008 complains. Thanks for the pointer, at least.

Comment: Finally got back to this - after rebooting, VS 2008 no longer complained. I haven't tried to develop Silverlight in VS 2008, but at least I'm not nagged any more.